# TypeError not a function in recursive method of Javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, recursion, prototype

```
VisualHelper.prototype.setManageMode = function (target, level=0) {
    var self = this;

    /* Some operations ......*/

    target.children(":not(.Vhelper_button)").each(function (){
        console.log(self)
        console.log(self.setManageMode)
        self.setManageMode($(this), level+1)
    })
}
```

I have created a class called VisualHelper and one of its prototype methods as shown in the code snippet, with irrelevant parts omitted. The method takes a Jquery Object `target` and a int value `level`. My problem is, inside the recursion part, `target.children.each(...)`,
the variable `self` got referenced to `Window` instead of the object `this`, and then I got `self.setManageMode` is not a function TypeError. Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: The `self.setManageMode($(this), level+1)` calls looks good. Are you using the method anywhere else? Make sure to look at the stack trace.

Comment: Could you provide the part of the code where you call the function, as well as the relevant surrounding code?